# How to replace text in column Datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview

I have **DataGridView** that is filled from `DataSource`:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

bs.DataSource = reader.local();

dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

Where `reader.local();` returns data from class Model:

```
class ClientJson
    {

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string secondname { get; set; }
        public int sex { get; set; }
}
```

How to replace value in field `sex` to custom text as (male, female)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to or cannot change your model you can use `CellFormatting` event to replace cell values:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("sex"))
    {
        int? sex = e.Value as int?;

        // replace statement checks with your own conditions
        if(sex == 0)
        {
            e.Value  = "Male";
        }
        else if(sex == 1)
        {
            e.Value = "Female";
        }
        else
        {
            e.Value = "Unknown";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you considered changing the type of the property to "string"?

something like this

```
public string Sex
 {
    get
    {
        return this.sex;
    }
    set
    {
       if(value == "1")
          this.sex = "male";
       else
          this.sex = "female";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a property with only get and into thist put you logic. an example :

```
public string Gender{ get{ return this.sex==1?"Male":"female";}}
```

and you bind only new property Gender.

Answer (score 0):

**do you mean like this?**

```
public string Sex
 {
    get
    {
        return this.sex;
    }
    set
    {
this.sex=value=="1"?"male":"female";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, seem it that I need